# Профессия мужского рода + глагол женского рода

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, род

Подскажите, как правильно:

*автор написал **(написала**);

архитектор приложил (**приложила**) руку.*

Как грамотно, если автор или архитектор — женщина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сказуемое в книжно-письменных стилях (особенно в строгой официально-деловой речи) ставится в форме мужского рода: 1) при отсутствии собственного имени; 2) если сказуемое предшествует сочетанию «рассматриваемое слово + собственное имя»: **Диссертант изложил интересные наблюдения. Уже известный читателям автор предложил новую статью. Увлекательные заметки предложил редакции известный автор Н. Петрова.**

б) сказуемое ставится в форме женского рода, если оно стоит после собственного имени: Автор Н. Петрова предложила редакции увлекательные заметки. Диссертант Иванова изложила интересные наблюдения.

в) сказуемое может быть поставлено в женском роде, если его форма является единственным показателем того, что речь идет о женщине, а пишущему важно это подчеркнуть: Автор – штурман авиационного женского полка ночных бомбардировщиков – посвятила свою повесть памяти боевых подруг.

> *Постановка определения или сказуемого в форме женского рода в условиях, не отвечающих перечисленным выше, свойственна разговорному стилю.*

Подробнее здесь: [Автор Петрова, или Названия «неженских» профессий](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89)