# «...работала её тренер Любовь Серебрянская». Верно согласование? Какое правило подходит?

Tags: существительные

«...работала её тренер Любовь Серебрянская».

Answer (score 1):

Для профессии тренер нет парного наименования женского рода. В подобных случаях в литературной и разговорной речи согласование происходит по-разному. 
В вашем предложении **сказуемое предшествует названию професии и имени персонажа**, поэтому книжно-письменный стиль требует постановки сказуемого в форме мужского рода:

**...работал ее тренер Любовь Серебрянская**

В разговорном стиле сказуемое ставится в форме женского рода:

**..работала ее тренер Любовь Серебрянская**

Подробности [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89).

Comment: а как же: при сочетании в подлежащем нарицательного сущ. с именем собственным сказуемое согласуется с именем собственным....т. е. Серебрянская согласуется с «работала»....

Comment: Думаю, у нас разные источники. Мой оставляет место для обоих вариантов, объясняя это наличием разный стилей, но утверждает, что строгой литературной норме соответствует такой пример: "Увлекательные заметки предложил редакции известный автор Н. Петрова". Так что решайте сами.

Comment: См. также на этом сайте: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431694/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB/431695

Comment: Розенталь даёт род имени собственного...

Comment: В товарищах-филологах согласья нет :) Так что повторяю: решайте сами.

Comment: решу, ок, спасибо)

Comment: @ flossyU, противоречия в справочниках нет.  В справочнике Розенталя приведены примеры со сказуемом в пост позиции. В этом случае и в деловой речи сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим. Если же сказуемое предшествует названию профессии ( о чем не сказано в этом справочнике) , то соглосование происходит с нарицательным именем существительным.  На Грамоте тот же справочник, но 2013 г., дополненный и исправленный.